# TSLint and React stateless component naming (PascalCase vs. camelCase)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

Stateless React components should be named in [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase), so React can distinguish between native elements and components. [Typescripts naming convention](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines) dictates that we should use lowerCamelCase or UPPER_CASE for the name of const variables.

How can I satisfy both (React and tslint)?

[image: Explanation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two options here:

1. Use where appopriate comment like this

   `/* tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name */`

   to disable tslint warning at that particular line
2. Use class components instead of functional ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe this is another solution: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/variable-name/

Comment: If you will allow both pascal case and camel case - this will effectively kill the purpose of the check. As the most common problem is the mix of the mentioned styles - and tslint is a good tool to prevent this.

Comment: Can't we just allow `PascalCase` for `StatelessComponent<S>` type?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following rule in you tslint.json:

```
"variable-name": [true, "ban-keywords", "check-format", "allow-pascal-case"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a compromise, using a function declaration instead of a variable declaration for my component:

[image]